# Number of ways for a knight to move to a certain square on a chessboard

Tags: combinatorics

I was wondering whether there was a formula to find the number of ways a knight could move to a certain square on a chessboard in a set number of moves; for example, if it started at the bottom left square (0,0) and had to get to e5 (4,4) in 8 moves. Would this change if the board was infinite (not confined to quadrant 1) and or was done in an odd number of moves?

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically it is possible.

Consider the chessboard case of $8\times8$ grid.

Each of the 64 squares is a node in a graph, with two vertices being adjacent if a knight can move from one to the other.

This can be represented by a $64\times 64$ adjacency matrix $A$, where $A_{ij} = 1$ is there is an edge between node $i$ and $j$, and $A_{ij} = 0$ otherwise.

The $ij^{th}$ entry of $A^k$ gives the number of ways to get from node $i$ to node $j$ in exacty $k$ steps (this allows for repeats).

If $A$ is diagonalizable, then you get a formula as a linear combination of powers of the eigenvalues of $A$.

For the infinite case, if you are looking for $k$ steps, you need to pick a grid of larger size (say $4k$) and reduce it to the finite case. The matrix will be dependent on $k$ though and might not give a neat formula.